# Что такое Android Support Repository?

Tags: android-studio, android

Зачем нужен *Android Support Repository*? Что он делает и содержит?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Android Support Repository* - локальная копия на вашем компьютере репозитория Maven, которая содержит скомпилированные версии (.aar) библиотек поддержки Google (такие, как *support:appcompat*, *support:design* , *support:v7* и тд.)

Находится по пути: `\Android\Sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support`

Используется для оффлайн работы IDE и ускорения сборки проекта, так как в этом случае не требуется выкачивать эти библиотеки из интернета, когда они понадобятся в проекте, она получает их с вашего компьютера.

Если вы не используете никаких библиотек поддержки Google, то локальная копия репозитория вам ни к чему, однако в современной андроид-разработке трудно представить приложение, которое не использует этих библиотек.

*Android Support Library* -локальная копия исходных кодов библиотек поддержки Google.
Используется для того, чтобы, собственно, посмотреть, как там все устроено, скопировать ресурсы для кастомизации, сделать кастомные вью на основе виджетов библиотек поддержки и тп.

Comment: OK, спасибо за подробный ответ!

Comment: @Иван [Что делать, когда кто то ответил на мой вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Не знаю. Научите.

Answer (score 1):

Это репозиторий вспомогательных библиотек. Хранит в себе тонну всевозможных библиотек, которые можно использовать.

Comment: То есть, если я не использую явно библиотеки оттуда, то он и не нужен?